# What algorithms are there to partition graphs into bounded-diameter sets?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, computer-science, network

I'm working on a project in which I have a large graph, and I want to break it into clusters of nodes. Connected components turned out to be too loose a restriction, so I want to impose a diameter bound on the components as well (i.e. any two nodes in the same component are < d edges apart). Do there exist practical  algorithms to do this efficiently? I considered a modified BFS, but ideally, the algorithm should give the same result independent of the node ordering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two such *community detection* algorithms are Louvain and label propagation.  For any resulting community that exceeds the diameter threshold, you can recursively apply either algorithm as needed.